# Typeahead implementation for dropdown

Tags: angularjs, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I am creating typeahead for dropdown. I used angularjs-typeahead-dropdown.min . But its not working. Below is my code

```
    <head>
        <script src="src/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Typeahead.js"></script>
        <script src="src/angularjs-typeahead-dropdown.min.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
<div class="container">
      <typeahead-dropdown id="ex1" ng-model="ex1model" options="ex1data" config="ex1config"></typeahead-dropdown>
    </div>
```

in js file

```
$scope.ex1model = [];
    $scope.ex1data = [{ id: 1, label: "Tony" },
               { id: 2, label: "Larita" },
               { id: 3, label: "Brian" },
               { id: 4, label: "Andrew" },
               { id: 5, label: "Bruno" },
               { id: 6, label: "Adrian" },
               { id: 7, label: "Stuart" },
               { id: 8, label: "Stephen" },
               { id: 9, label: "Peter" },
               { id: 10, label: "Alexander" }];
    $scope.ex1config = { modelLabel: "id", optionLabel: "label" };
```

This is not working. Nothing comes in html page. Please tell me how to implement typeahead for dropdown. Is there any other way. **I should not use jquery**

Answer (score 1):

You can use UI Bootstrap's Dropdown on an input box as follows

`<div uib-dropdown>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchKey" uib-dropdown-toggle>
    <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
        <li ng-repeat="data in ex1data | filter:searchKey">
             {{data.label}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>`

Check the documentation for UI Bootstrap dropdown [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend to use select2
this link will make u learn how to use it from scratch
[select2 for beginner](https://select2.github.io/)

this link will make you realise why to use it 
just have a look 
[Examples for select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: it is using jquery :(

Answer (score 0):

The angular team provides an implementation of typeahead in `ui.bootstrap`.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.
Search for the "Typeahead" section.

They provide example code. Installation instructions are on [their github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)